# Exemplos de uso da palavra "elação"?

Tags: significado, uso-de-palavras

Eu sempre ouvi esta expressão: ***"Tirar elações"*** que talvez possa ser reduzido à palavra ***"elação"***.

**Edit**: O Schilive indicou nos comentários que fiz confusão entre as palavras **elação** e [**ilação**](https://dicionario.priberam.org/ila%C3%A7%C3%A3o). Então vou reformular a pergunta e pedir exemplos de uso da palavra **elação** que não me parece ser de uso comum. Não me recordo de ter visto a palavra ser usada antes.

> [e·la·ção](https://dicionario.priberam.org/ela%C3%A7%C3%B5es)
>
> (fem. pl. de elação)
>
> nome feminino
>
> 1. Altivez.
> 2. Elevação; sublimidade.

Comment: Será que estás fazendo confusão entre *elação* e *ilação*?

Comment: Você quer exemplos de uso da palavra "elação" ou quer saber o que é "tirar ilações"? No primeiro caso, será que uma pesquisa por "elação" em um mecanismo de busca não lhe trará resultados? No último caso, a definição da palavra "ilação", como consta no dicionário, não satisfaz sua busca?

Comment: @LoremIpsum eu editei a pergunta depois da clarificação do Schilive nos comentários. O que eu quero são exemplos de uso de "elação". Tentei no google e eram páginas e páginas só de dicionário/definição. Não me recordo de alguma vez ter visto um exemplo de aplicação da palavra, por isso também são bem vindos exemplos na literatura que tenham alguma relevo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Realmente, no exemplo de uso citado, "**tirar elação**" talvez tenha sido confundido com "**tirar ilação**".

Agora, dando **exemplos** do uso da palavra **elação**:

---

> **Na literatura**, definido como:
>
> 1. Altivez.
> 2. **Elevação; sublimidade.**
>
> **Exemplo**:
>
> "e no garbo com que regia o seu fogoso cavalo, assomavam os realces de uma alma elevada que tem consciência de sua superioridade, e sente ao passar pela Terra a **elação** das asas celestes."
>
> [**O Sertanejo**, José de Alencar](http://www.ebooksbrasil.org/eLibris/sertanejo.html)

---

> **Na psiquiatria**, definido como:
>
> "A **elação** (humor exaltado ou ativado) é uma aceleração dos processos psíquicos dentro de um campo vivencial alargado. A elevação de humor pode ser suspeita por verborragia, pressão de discurso, psicomotricidade intensificada e hiper-reatividade".
>
> **Exemplo**:
>
> "Ainda como parte desse quadro, tornou-se mais desinibida (tanto no aspecto verbal quanto psicomotor), com **elação** do humor, jocosidade, compartilhamento de piadas com desconhecidos, risonha e menor necessidade de sono e apetite."
>
> [**Psiquiatria Geriátrica**, Leonardo Caixeta](https://www.google.com.br/books/edition/Psiquiatria_Geri%C3%A1trica/hRMlCwAAQBAJ?hl=pt-BR&gbpv=0)

---

Comment: Obrigado pela citação do José de Alencar, quando pedi referências apesar de não dizer estava a pensar nos escritores do séc XIX.

Answer (score 4):

Olha, a única vez que eu me recordo ter visto "elação" utilizada corretamente foi como oposto a "depressão" em textos técnicos de psicologia.

Por exemplo, [no manual de Classificação de Transtornos Mentais e de Comportamento da CID-10](https://books.google.nl/books?id=QpYFEAAAQBAJ&pg=PA44&lpg=PA44&dq=CID%2010%20%22ela%C3%A7%C3%A3o%22&source=bl&ots=ZXffAGbnlQ&sig=ACfU3U09iIDwTIsJiN_Hqbtt0pi7Lk86gQ&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=CID%2010%20%22ela%C3%A7%C3%A3o%22&f=false) da OMS:

---

> **Transtornos mentais e de comportamento**
>
> **Introdução**
>
> (...)
>
> Nestes transtornos, a perturbação fundamental é uma alteração do humor ou afeto, usualmente para a depressão (com ou sem ansiedade associada) ou **elação**.

---

Em outros trechos do livro, "elação" é usada com o mesmo significado, em particular descrevendo a mania e outros transtornos associados, como esquizofrenia com episódios maníacos, ciclotimia e distimia.

Comment: Gostei da resposta por enquadrar e esclarecer bem o uso da palavra. Agora que leio esta resposta já me recordo ter visto a palavra ser usada em textos de psicologia. Não vou aceitar a resposta pela única razão de querer deixar a pergunta em aberto para o caso de alguém querer elaborar ou acrescentar mais alguma coisa.

Comment: Vou colocar um *bounty* para recompensar a qualidade da resposta.